# Flask app on Gunicorn + nginx 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, nginx, flask, raspberry-pi, gunicorn

I have a problem with deply of my flask app using nxginx and gunicorn. When I am checking nginx status it looks ok:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-25 20:10:46 CEST; 2s ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 2847 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2848 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2849 (nginx)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 8.7M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─2849 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─2850 nginx: worker process
           ├─2851 nginx: worker process
           ├─2852 nginx: worker process
           └─2853 nginx: worker process

sie 25 20:10:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
sie 25 20:10:46 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Gunicorn also looks fine:

```
● gunicorn.service - Gunicorn instance to serve peephole
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-25 20:12:11 CEST; 1s ago
 Main PID: 3017 (gunicorn)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 39.4M
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
           └─3017 /home/pi/Documents/Peephole/venv/bin/python /home/pi/Documents/Peephole/venv/bin/gunicorn --preload --workers 2 --tim

sie 25 20:12:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Gunicorn instance to serve peephole.
```

However when I am trying to access flask app via browser then I have `502 Bad Gateway` and in `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is see the following (where .151 is server on which I am trying to deply app, and .178 is my desktop):

```
2020/08/25 18:51:53 [crit] 530#530: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/", host: "192.168.0.151"
2020/08/25 18:51:54 [crit] 530#530: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.0.151", referrer: "http://192.168.0.151/"
2020/08/25 18:52:05 [crit] 530#530: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.0.151", referrer: "http://192.168.0.151/"
2020/08/25 19:00:20 [crit] 1299#1299: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/", host: "192.168.0.151"
2020/08/25 19:00:22 [crit] 1299#1299: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.0.151", referrer: "http://192.168.0.151/"
2020/08/25 19:48:32 [crit] 1300#1300: *6 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/", host: "192.168.0.151"
2020/08/25 19:48:38 [crit] 1300#1300: *6 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.0.151", referrer: "http://192.168.0.151/"
2020/08/25 20:12:29 [crit] 2850#2850: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/", host: "192.168.0.151"
2020/08/25 20:12:29 [crit] 2850#2850: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "192.168.0.151", referrer: "http://192.168.0.151/"
```

In project directory I can see that socket file exists, so its weird.

Also what's interesting, when I am stopping nginx and gunicorn via `sudo systemctl stop gunicorn` and `sudo systemctl stop nginx` and running `gunicorn --bind 192.168.0.151 -w 5 wsgi:app` my app is alive and possible to reach from desktop but it keeps restarting every 20 seconds.

Gunicorn configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve peephole
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pi
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/Documents/Peephole
Environment="PATH=/home/pi/Peephole/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/pi/Documents/Peephole/venv/bin/gunicorn --preload --workers 2 --timeout 120 --bind unix:peephole.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.0.151;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock;
    }
}
```

wsgi.py

```
from server import create_app

app = create_app()
```

Dont know if this is important but raspberry pi 4b 4gb is my server.

Comment: Where is your gunicorn config? Where did you get the socket path `http://unix:/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock` from?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the `/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock` file?

Comment: @jordanm gunicorn config path: ```/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service/```. Socket file has been created according to this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04 

@IvanVelichko file permissions: ```srwxrwx--- 1 pi www-data```

Comment: I see, that would be `/home/pi/Documents/Peephole/peephole.sock`, not `/home/pi/Peephole/peephole.sock`.

Comment: Wow, you are right.... so obvious... :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the `ExecStart` line in your supervisor file, try telling gunicorn to bind to all interfaces:

`--bind 0.0.0.0:8000`

Then in the nginx config, pass to this via HTTP instead of socket:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/
```

Comment: Done just like you said and it's working better. Now I am able to access app but it keeps restarting. In error.log i see:
```2020/08/25 20:57:59 [error] 4100#4100: *14 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.0.178, server: 192.168.0.151, request: "GET /profile?id=2&user_name=piotrek HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8000/profile?id=2&user_name=piotrek", host: "192.168.0.151", referrer: "http://192.168.0.151/profile?id=2&user_name=piotrek"```

Comment: @gawron103 Em.  This looks [like this](https://serverfault.com/a/576488/148942) something to do with an IPv6 request.  Try using `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/` instead, to specifically make it pass to the upstream using IPv4.